# Android Amplify change log level

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify

In swift, there is code to change loglevel in documentation
`Amplify.Logging.logLevel = .verbose`. But I didn't find any thing same in android to do this. I tried `Amplify.addPlugin(AndroidLoggingPlugin(LogLevel.VERBOSE))` and put `"logging": {"logLevel": "VERBOSE"}` in amplifyconfiguration.json, both didn't work. Anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing and found this from issue 2459 on github:
[SignIn flow hangs for consecutive custom challenges.](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/2459)

> `add Amplify.addPlugin(AndroidLoggingPlugin(LogLevel.VERBOSE))` before
> any other plugins in your configure block."

I am trying it out myself I hope it works!